# Return array_intersect as boolean

Tags: php

I have two arrays and I need to check if they have values in common and the return value must be a boolean.
Can I use `array_intersect()` like this or there is a better way?

```
$result = (bool) array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Thank you.

Comment: all the values?

Comment: it depenends on how your arrays are build... if you are using multidimensional arrays than it will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Just check the content of `array_intersect($array1, $array2)`

```
$result = count(array_intersect($array1, $array2)) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code will work fine. When casting to a boolean, an empty array is considered false, while an array with any elements in it (i.e. one for which `count($array) > 0`) will be considered as true. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered **FALSE**: 
>   ... 
>   - an array with zero elements 
>   ... 
>   Every other value is considered **TRUE** (including any resource and NAN).

Answer (score 1):

Count values that intersects:

```
$result = count(array_intersect($array1, $array2)) !== 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

if one value

```
$marks = array(100, 65, 70, 87); 
$sparks = array(100, 40, 20, 200);  
if (in_array($sparks[0], $marks))  // can make this dynamic too, returns bool
  { 
  echo "found"; 
  } 
else
  { 
  echo "not found"; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use boolval( array_intersect($array1, $array2) )

It will return true if there are any entries in the return array and false of it is empty.